# A Book Errata in a Derivative. I am missing something?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This part is drive me crazy. Or I am missing something in the derivative problem?

[image: Book derivative page]

My answer:

[image: Answer derivative]

I will appreciate any help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, differentiating $$y = \frac{z}{2(z+1)}$$ by the quotient rule give us:
$$y' = \frac{2(z+1)(1) - z(2)}{4(z+1)^2}=\frac{2z + 2 - 2z}{4(z+1)^2} = \frac{1}{2(z+1)^2}.
$$

Comment: Freaking book, was driving me crazy. Thank you very much.